# How do I get the background color only behind the text?

Tags: html, css, text, background

This is my code but I want the text to only have background color[image] behind it, and not stretch across the entire screen?[image] Any ideas?

```
   .section_title {
      background-color: orange;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0px auto;
    }
```

HTML is

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="section_title">
    <h2>Choose a Pack to Print</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does the HTML markup look like? show some html code

Comment: (added HTML to above question)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566100/css-h1-only-as-wide-as-the-text

Answer (score 1):

An option is adding `display: inline-block;` to the CSS of the text element.

Comment: You may also need to add Bootstrap's `text-center` class to the parent element, and it looks like you'll want to add some horizontal padding to get the width shown in your image.

Comment: I'm not sure this works in order for it to be responsive for a phone screen

Answer (score 1):

One problem I found with `display: inline-block;` is it clears floats incorrectly. Instead, I use `width: fit-content;`

```css
.highlight {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 0.5em;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="highlight">Highlight for text only!</h1>
<h1 class="highlight">Highlight me too!</h1>
```

Comment: This still doesn't work for multi-line H1 titles, etc.

Comment: @JesseNickles could you elaborate what you mean? If you are seeking "ragged edge" on multi-line, this wasn't a factor in the SO question - for that you'd need `display: inline`. More intel here https://css-tricks.com/multi-line-padded-text/ and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709313/css-background-color-on-multi-line-text

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to do this, but probably the best way is to make the `h2` `inline` or `inline-block`.

Using `inline-block` will allow you to set width/height.

```
.section-title {
  text-align: center;
}
.section-title h2 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

The other way to do this is to set a width on the h2 and set the margin to `auto`;

```
.section-title h2 { 
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%; /* for example */
}
```

If you want all your headings to be a set width, I'd choose the second one (allowing for text to wrap). If you want the box to be flexible and hug the contents, I'd use the first.