# How can this link span the text and not the horizontal length of the document?

Tags: html

I want 'Upcoming Shows' to be a link to an external site -- but the link spans the entire block -- the width of the page.

What is the simplest way to have it just span the text instead?

```
<div class="content">
      <a href="https://www.songkick.com/artists/8458448-exlegionnaires/calendar" target="_blank"><h1>Upcoming Shows</h1></a>
      <ul>
        <li> 7/23 Spider House Ballroom (ATX) w/Honey and Salt, Holy Smokes</li>
        <li> 7/30 Cheer Up Charlies (ATX) w/Killer Ghost</li>
        <li> 8/9 Hotel Vegas (ATX) w/Golden Boys, Party Dress, TBD</li>
        <li> 8/22 Hole in The Wall (ATX) w/Hex Dispensers, Popper Burns</li>
        <li> 9/13 Swan Dive (ATX) w/Rare Birds, Soaked</li>
      </ul>
```

Comment: `<h1>` elements are block level elements and occupy the full width of their parent container by default. Maybe you'd prefer to use a `<span>`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use css to make it display as block with the customised width (or with 100% if you have specified with of the block above):

```
a {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Or you can embed this css in your html tag:

```
<a style="display: block">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:inline-block` in the css
, so:

```
h1{
    display:inline-block
    //rest of css stylings...
}
```

See also:  [css h1 - only as wide as the text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566100/css-h1-only-as-wide-as-the-text)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put `display: inline;`
Here is working fiddle:

```css
h1 {
    display:inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="content"> <a href="https://www.songkick.com/artists/8458448-exlegionnaires/calendar" target="_blank"><h1>Upcoming Shows</h1></a>

    <ul>
        <li>7/23 Spider House Ballroom (ATX) w/Honey and Salt, Holy Smokes</li>
        <li>7/30 Cheer Up Charlies (ATX) w/Killer Ghost</li>
        <li>8/9 Hotel Vegas (ATX) w/Golden Boys, Party Dress, TBD</li>
        <li>8/22 Hole in The Wall (ATX) w/Hex Dispensers, Popper Burns</li>
        <li>9/13 Swan Dive (ATX) w/Rare Birds, Soaked</li>
    </ul>
```